# Dockerfile CMD curl --noproxy * arguments with space do not work

Tags: docker, curl, dockerfile

I meet a strange thing today.
Here is the steps:

1.I run the cmd below and it's the output:

```
shshenhx@shshenhx:~/Desktop/Docker/IP$ curl --noproxy '*' http://ip.cn
当前 IP：202.101.0.2 来自：上海市 电信 <====The cmd get my public IP 
successfully
```

2. Then I got a Dockerfile and the content like this:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y curl \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl --noproxy '*' http://ip.cn  <==Here I run the cmd directly
```

The output is still

```
shshenhx@shshenhx:~/Desktop/Docker/IP$ curl --noproxy '*' http://ip.cn
当前 IP：202.101.0.2 来自：上海市 电信
```

3.If I change the last line to CMD model like this:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y curl \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

CMD ["curl" ,  "--noproxy '*'" , "http://ip.cn"]
```

Then I got the error like this:

```
shshenhx@shshenhx:~/Desktop/Docker/IP$ docker run myip
curl: option --noproxy '*': is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Could anyone figure the issue here? Why I can run curl cmd using RUN in dockerfile, but failed using CMD ?

Answer (score 2):

Each space that is not a part of an argument requires a `,`

```
CMD [ "curl" ,  "--noproxy", "*" , "http://ip.cn" ]
```

The `*` doesn't need to be quoted in this case ether as there isn't a shell that will expand the `*` to the files in the current directory, the arguments are passed directly to the `curl` binary.